# How to reference variables in a new class?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program which consists of multiple classes. One class is called "User" and the other one is called "userGroup". I'm trying to import a variable which is contained within a constructor from the User class and use it in the userGroup class.

I've tried the following code:

```
User userRetrieve = new User();
userRetrieve.User();
```

This code doesn't seem to work, although I have seen in various tutorials that this is how you would retrieve data from another class. The second line has ".User()" because the constructor is also called User but I am not sure if this is correct and even if it was the initial problem of the program not recognizing the first line would still remain.

I'll show the code form both classes for extra information which may show where I have gone wrong:

User class:

```
public class User {

    String username;
    String userType;
    String name;

    public User() {
        username = "x";
        userType = "y";
        name = "z";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String setUserType(String admin) {
        return userType = admin;
    }

}
```

userGroup class:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class userGroup {

    String User;

    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<>(); 

    Integer user0;

    public void addSampleData() {

    userArray.add(new User());

    }

    public void getUser(User user0)  {

       user0 = userArray.get(0);

    }

    public void printusername()  {

        System.out.println(user0.getUserName()); // x 


    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the username and userType variables in the constructor from the User class.

P.S Apologies for any formatting/indentation errors.

Comment: Why not use the get methods in class User?

Comment: You don't need 10 users to show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstrood some concepts. Firstly the `User()` method is the constructor so when you do `User user = new User()` that method is called. I suggest this change to your user class

```
public class User {

  private String username;
  private String userType;
  private String name;

  // Use constructor to pass data to your class
  public User(String username, String userType, String name) {
    this.username = username;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
      return username;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
      return userType;
  }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public String setUserType(String admin) {
      return userType = admin;
  }


}
```

Now you can create your array and add a user, then retrieve its information

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
users.add(new User("x", "y", "z"));

users.get(0).getUsername(); // returns "x"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of users

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>()
```

Add a user

```
users.add(new User());
```

Get a user (lists and arrays are zero-indexed)

```
User user0 = users.get(0);
```

Print some properties

```
System.out.println(user0.getUserName()); // x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the get methods you created in the constructor class?

So if you want to get the username and the userType just create a new variable using the get method

```
User userRetrieve = new User();
String username = userRetrieve.getUsername();
String userType = userRetrieve.getUserType();
```

Or alternatively you could just directly access the variables:

```
User userRetrieve = new User();
String username = userRetrieve.username;
String userType = userRetrieve.userType;
```

Comment: This works apart form one error. The error is that it does not recognize User as a symbol. I'm not too sure why this is because that is the name of the other class.

Comment: are the classes within the same folder/package when compiling?

Comment: Yeah I just double checked.

Comment: what IDE are you using? If it's eclipse, try hitting Project -> Clean. This usually resolves type errors

Answer (score 0):

```
User userRetrieve = new User();
```

On this line you are instantiating a new object of type `Person`,
you do this by calling the constructor associated with this particular class.

After you have done this it is possible to acces parameters by calling the various methods you have defined in the `Person` class. So in your case you should use `userRetrieve.getUsername()` and so on.. you will however need to declare a variable in the calling class to store these values in.